# Create arrow in :after with inset border radius

Tags: html, css, electron, rounded-corners

I'm I'm trying to create an arrow which points to the top. The arrow is currently a basic CSS `after` pseudo class. However, I the left and right side of the arrow need to have some kind of "inset" border radius. Any ideas how to fix this?

Since this concerns an Electron menubar app, the outer part needs to be transparent.

[image]

This is what I currently came up with:
https://jsfiddle.net/xcpo1g2y/

Comment: @ovokuro I added a JSFiddle link to my post :)

Comment: @Pete Box shadow is not a solution to this problem I guess. I need the border radius on the left/right side to be smooth instead of just a static arrow (check out my Fiddle)

Comment: sorry totally misread the question, perhaps you need a png image for the arrow, the bottom curve doesn't dip below the line so it can be done with a png.  Not sure how you would do it with pure css though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe a start - but I'm using an extra element and it feels a bit hacky. The idea is to make the inverted border radius by having a large rectangle in the color you want, and you cover up the edges covered with shapes with `border-bottom-right-radius` and `border-bottom-left-radius` set.

I didn't round the top of the arrow, but that would certainly be possible by using your border radius and rotation transform approach.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.header {
  background: rgba(235,238,243,1);
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

/* Left flange */
.header:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: none;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 25px solid black;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  transform: translateX(-137%);
  z-index: 2;
}

/* Right flange */
.header:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: none;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 25px solid black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  transform: translateX(37%);
  z-index: 2;
}

/* Arrow base */
.header-helper {
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

/* Up arrow */
.header-helper:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border: 25px solid black;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"><div class='header-helper'></div></div>
```

Comment: Nice one! Thanks :)